# How does SQL Server know what index to use?

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index

I have this non clustered index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_wi_StoreVariantInventory_F09B4BE817BC953FAC6861B7E46F6F51] ON [dbo].[StoreVariantInventory]
(
    [ProductId] ASC,
    [StoreId] ASC,
    [VariantId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [LocalInventory]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And this clustered index

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StoreVariantInventory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_StoreVariantInventory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductId] ASC,
    [ChainId] ASC,
    [CountryCode] ASC,
    [StoreId] ASC,
    [VariantId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Generated for this table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StoreVariantInventory](
    [ProductId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ChainId] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [CountryCode] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [StoreId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [VariantId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Size] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SizeRow] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [KoncernNumber] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [LocalInventory] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderedInventory] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [money] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StoreVariantInventory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductId] ASC,
    [ChainId] ASC,
    [CountryCode] ASC,
    [StoreId] ASC,
    [VariantId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StoreVariantInventory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StoreVariantInventory_Stores] FOREIGN KEY([StoreId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Stores] ([StoreId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StoreVariantInventory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StoreVariantInventory_Stores]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StoreVariantInventory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StoreVariantInventory_Variants] FOREIGN KEY([ProductId], [VariantId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Variants] ([ProductId], [VariantId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StoreVariantInventory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StoreVariantInventory_Variants]
GO
```

If I do a simple select

```
select LocalInventory
from StoreVariantInventory
where ProductId=1219100110 
and VariantId = 49 
and StoreId = 9050 
and ChainId = 'F'
```

It looks through the non clustered index
[image: Non clustered index]

But why does it pick the non clustered index? I am doing a WHERE that doesn't fit the non clustered index 100% so how can it use it? Does SQL Server just picks what it seems a best fit, when all columns in the WHERE clause doesn't fit an index 100%? Is it bad practice not having an index like here not fitting 100% with my where clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>*Answer originally left as a comment by [i-one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/99746/i-one)*:</sub>

Your query references *ProductId, VariantId, StoreId, ChainId* and *LocalInventory* columns.

All of them except *ChainId* are declared in the non-clustered index definition.

*ChainId* is included in the non-clustered index implicitly as part of the clustered index key.

So, the non-clustered index is covering for this query.

---

The nonclustered index contains the clustered index keys because SQL Server must be able to locate the base table row from the index entry.

From the [SQL Server Index Architecture and Design Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-2017#column-considerations-2):

> If the table has a clustered index, the column or columns defined in the clustered index are automatically appended to the end of each nonclustered index on the table. This can produce a covered query without specifying the clustered index columns in the definition of the nonclustered index. For example, if a table has a clustered index on column `C`, a nonclustered index on columns `B` and `A` will have as its key values columns `B`, `A`, and `C`.